# Building keras and tensor flow on yocto

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto

I have been trying to build keras and tensor flow packages on yocto's image that is poky but not able to do so.

Until now I have tried looking for their respective recipe but couldn't find.
What's the way to add keras and tensor flow packages to poky?

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. `but not able to do so` That looks like you encountered an error. Please also add the error message

Comment: With respect to keras and tensorflow I have not tried anything since the recipes itself were not available, the only other thing I heard of is to compile from source by cloning their repos. Which I don't know how to do. So can you let me know what are the ways to add keras and tensorflow packages to yocto's image poky?

Comment: Can you tell what is the target machine?

Answer (score 4):

From the layer index, it appears that there isn't an existing recipe to build either [tensorflow](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=tensorflow) or [keras](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=keras) .
You'll have to create the recipe yourself or open a [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=tensorflow&list_id=606307) request to have it added and hope that someone has the time to do that.

Writing a new recipe for a large package such as tensorflow is quite a bit of work so I can't tell you exactly how to do it here but I can give you pointers to the relevant YP documentation and community.

To write the recipe, there are [guidelines](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-writing-a-new-recipe) in the Yocto Documentation. You should be sure that you have built an image such as core-image-minimal and added a [simple recipe](http://www.variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Hello_World) as well as examined similar recipes in the oe-core and meta-openembedded.

If you get stuck ask for help using one of the forums listed in the [Community section](https://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) of the OpenEmbedded wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](https://github.com/renesas-rz/meta-renesas-ai) layer on Github that might be a good starting point.

It seems to have all the recipes to include TensorFlow in your Yocto build. I would start by adding the `meta-tensorflow` to my `bblayers.conf` and adding `tensorflow` to `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` then run it, see what errors come out an try to take it from there.

Not sure about Keras, but what I understand from the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) is that it should be part of TensorFlow.